# How to pass data to the database with javascript and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating this functionality where user can like a product and unlike it with javascript, if user likes the product it should add to the database and also if he unlike the product it should be deleted in database. Everything works fine in normal way but if I use javascript, the like button isn't working and either not adding anything in database same thing applies for unlike button. How can I make this work (like and unlike this should work in database too not changing the icons of like and unlike)?

Javascript

```
  // Like product
  function addToFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: `/product/like/${productid}`,
    data: {
        'user_id': userid,
        'product_id': productid,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
        $('#addfavourites' + productid).hide();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});



   // Unlike product
function deleteFromFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: `product/${productid}/unlike`, 
    data: {
        'user_id': userid,
        'product_id': productid,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
        $('#addfavourites' + productid).hide();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Route

```
  Route::post('product/like/{id}', ['as' => 'product.like', 'uses' => 'LikeController@likeProduct']);
  Route::post('product/{product}/unlike', 'LikeController@destroy')->name('product.unlike');
```

Blade File

```
  @if($product->isLiked)
  <div id="deletefavourite{{$product->id}}"onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})"> unlike </div>
   @else
   <div id="addfavourites{{$product->id}}" onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>
@endif
```

How I add to favorite

```
    public function likeProduct($id)
{


    if(Auth::check()){
    $this->handleLike(Product::class, $id);
    return redirect()->back();
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('login')
    }
}

public function handleLike($type, $id)
{
    $existing_like = Like::withTrashed()->whereLikeableType($type)->whereLikeableId($id)->whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();

    if (is_null($existing_like)) {
        Like::create([
            'user_id'       => Auth::id(),
            'likeable_id'   => $id,
            'product_id'   => $id,
            'likeable_type' => $type,
        ]);
    } else {
        if (is_null($existing_like->deleted_at)) {
            $existing_like->delete();
        } else {
            $existing_like->restore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check ajax call or not?

Comment: what do you mean? @Jinesh

Comment: When you click on like button it will call ajax or not?

Comment: when i click like i see this error on console `1(index):508 Uncaught ReferenceError: addToFavourites is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick` @Jinesh

Comment: can you tell me where your write addToFavourites this function? If possible share your view files

Comment: I have updated question with the function @Jinesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201834/discussion-between-jinesh-and-joh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not completed curly braces of function check my code

```
function addToFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: `/product/like/${productid}`,
    data: {
        'user_id': userid,
        'product_id': productid,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
console.log($('#addfavourites' + productid));
        $('#addfavourites' + productid).hide();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});

}

   // Unlike product
function deleteFromFavourites(productid, userid) {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: `product/${productid}/unlike`, 
    data: {
        'user_id': userid,
        'product_id': productid,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
console.log($('#addfavourites' + productid));
        $('#addfavourites' + productid).hide();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + productid).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must check in network for see request and response from inspect element
this thing will make you can follow problem . you may have a problem with route so please 
check the network during post request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest change routes. I mean, use same pattern for both actions: like and unlike

```
Route::post('product/like/{id}', ['as' => 'product.like', 'uses' => 'LikeController@likeProduct']);
Route::post('product/unlike/{id}', 'LikeController@destroy')->name('product.unlike');
```

Then inspect what you see on server, log incoming data. It should help to understand, why you algorithm didn't work.

Second, you have to render both div's in your blade template

```
   <div class="CLASS_SHOW_ITEM" id="deletefavourite{{$product- >id}}"onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})"> unlike </div>
   <div class="CLASS_HIDE_ITEM" id="addfavourites{{$product->id}}" onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>
```

You have to choose class by value of attribute **$product->isLiked**

Comment: I see this error on console `1(index):508 Uncaught ReferenceError: addToFavourites is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick` @Eugene